# FFMPEG - Convert DTS-Audio to AC3 - But Keep Original Video and Audio Files

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

i am having trouble to understand the documentation on [FFMPEG-Website](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

Can you please help me out?

> So far i got an working command for converting the DTS to AC3 but overwrite the original DTS

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i File.mkv -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640k File.mkv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the audio stream twice and specify which audio stream needs to be reencoded:

```
ffmpeg -i File.mkv -map 0 -map 0:a -c copy -c:a:1 ac3 -b:a:1 640k File.mkv
```

Using `-c copy` yields the most compact cli command but produces an ignorable warning:

```
Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 3, only the last option '-c:a:1 ac3' will be used.
```

If this bothers you, you can specify each separately instead:

```
-c:v copy -c:a copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 ac3
```

All above assume that the original audio stream to be presented first. If you want to swap their order, just swap `a:0` and `a:1` everywhere.

Comment: Hello again! I have now a stream where this command doesn't work: 
Stream has 
`1 Video`
`3 audio streams: DTS XLL/MLP FBA 16-ch/AC-3`
`C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i input_file.mkv -map 0 -map 0:a -c copy -c:a:1 ac3 -b:a:1 640k output_file.mkv`

i have 6 audio streams in the output-file:
`6 audio streams: DTS XLL/AC-3/AC-3/DTS XLL/MLP FBA 16-ch/AC-3`
**There are supposed to be 4, what did i do wrong?**

Comment: `-map 0:a` maps all audio streams of the 1st input file (thus doubling all of them). If you have more than one audio, pick the stream you want to re-encode by specifying the specific stream. If it's the 1st, then use `-map 0:a:0` if 2nd, `-amp 0:a:1` and so forth

Comment: Input-File:
`3 audio streams: DTS XLL/MLP FBA 16-ch/AC-3`
Output-File:
`4 audio streams: AC-3\MLP FBA 16-ch/AC-3/DTS XLL`
Code:
`ffmpeg -i File.mkv -map 0 -map 0:a:0 -c copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k File.mkv`

Thanks as expected

Comment: One Last Question:

If i want to have an Output like this:

Output:
`4 audio streams: DTS XLL\MLP FBA 16-ch/AC-3/AC-3 (Converted DTS)`

I appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Comment: I believe streams are mapped in the order specified. So, if you need to alter the original order, you need to break down `-map 0` into the exact order you'd like, e.g., `-map 0:v -map 0:a:1 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:0` to map the 2nd audio stream first, then the first and its transcoded copy

Comment: ah ok sounds good, thanks again your help spared me tears by trying this

Comment: I found another likely error in your command `-c:a:0 ac3` converts the first output stream, which is the first audio stream included by `-map 0`. To, encoding the last output stream mapped by `-map 0:a:0`, you need to spec `-c:a:3 ac3` instead. Yeah, I know it's confusing, but just remember that the stream specifiers on output options are those of the output streams and not the mapped input streams.

Comment: Thanks sir
the problem is i wanted to make this universal - sometimes when i download there are only two audio streams and i woult have to rewrite `-c:a:3 ac3` to `-c:a:2 ac3` - and i am using this as a batch - so the number of audio streams is always "x"